# What does the \newbox command do?

Tags: box

I've searched everywhere on this website and google for a tutorial but I don't see many, which I thought it was weird.

I've found this page https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes but it still doesn't explain what the newbox command does.

Comment: Welcome! `\setbox` allows you to define a new box that you can set e.g. with `\setbox`. You can then copy it with `\copy`. E.g. `\documentclass{article}
\newbox\Rainbox
\setbox\Rainbox\hbox{Rainbow}
\begin{document}
\copy\Rainbox
\end{document`. It is hard to just discuss `\newbox` without discussing the full concept of boxes in TeX.

Comment: what is then the difference between setbox and newbox?

Comment: @Rainb `\newbox` allocates a new box register (much like allocating a variable in other programming languages). `\setbox` adds stuff to that box.

Comment: `\setbox` tells TeX that what follows is a box. Just drop `\newbox\Rainbox` from the above example to see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition reads

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 339:
\def\newbox   {\e@alloc\box
                  {\ifnum\allocationnumber<\@cclvi
                     \expandafter\chardef
                   \else
                     \expandafter\e@alloc@chardef
                   \fi}
                                        {\count14}\insc@unt\float@count}
```

Uh, not really helpful, is it? OK, we know that `\newbox` should be followed by a control sequence name, let's say it's `\foo`. We need to look at `\e@alloc`:

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 386:
\def\e@alloc#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \global\advance#3\@ne
  \e@ch@ck{#3}{#4}{#5}#1%
  \allocationnumber#3\relax
  \global#2#6\allocationnumber
  \wlog{\string#6=\string#1\the\allocationnumber}}%
```

Well it takes six arguments. Let's see what they are when we call `\newbox\foo`.

- `#1` is `\box`
- `#2` is `\ifnum\allocationnumber...\fi`
- `#3` is `\count14`
- `#4` is `\insc@unt`
- `#5` is `\float@count`
- `#6` is `\foo`

The last allocation number for a `\box` register is `\count14` (this can be seen in `source2e`); so the first step is to increase it by one. Then

```
\e@ch@ck{\count14}{\ins@count}{\float@count}\box
```

is executed. I won't get into the details, but this chooses a new number based on already done allocations; one has to take into account that insertions and floats allocate box registers. Anyway, at the end of the process, `\allocationnumber` is set to the chosen integer value, (unless there is no room for a new box register, which is unlikely as there are 32768 of them; in this case an error will be raised.

In the normal case the next step is performed, that is

```
\global#2#6\allocationnumber
```

If the chosen number is less than 256, this becomes

```
\global\chardef\foo\allocationnumber
```

otherwise it becomes

```
\global\mathchardef\foo\allocationnumber
```

In either case, `\foo` becomes essentially equivalent to the allocated number.

When `\box\foo` is called, this will be the same as specifying the box register number (with the advantage we never need to know the precise number).

If you use the recommended LaTeX command, namely `\newsavebox{\foo}`, an initial step is performed: LaTeX checks whether `\foo` is not yet defined. In this case `\newbox\foo` is executed; otherwise an error is raised and the definition is ignored.

---

This is quite different from other register allocations. For instance, if you do `\newlength\foo`, this eventually becomes

```
\skipdef\foo=<number>
```

where the number is determined in the same way as before. This allows to use `\foo` in all situations where TeX expects a length or a length register name.

TeX has no `\boxdef` command, because box registers are rather peculiar and one can use them in a variety of ways:

```
\box\foo
\copy\foo
\unhbox\foo
\unvbox\foo
\unhcopy\foo
\unvcopy\foo
```

and so a `\boxdef` token would be completely useless.

The other usage is `\setbox\foo<box specification>` by which a box register is populated. Reading the TeXbook or TeX by Topic about this is recommended.

Comment: @campa Thanks, fixed